# GWT maven plugin - Unexpected internal compiler error

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-plugin

I am trying to upgrade old GWT project to run it with Java 17 (originally java 8,Wildfly 18). The app is packaged as war file that is goig to be deployed to Wildfly 24. No changes in code were made. When executing maven package goal,
the gwt maven plugin configured as below is constantly producing IllegalArgumentException. The only solution I was able to find was about outdated asm jar but even usage of the newest version does not bring anything.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <localWorkers>2</localWorkers>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xms512M -Xmx512M</extraJvmArgs>
                <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Those are dependencies in pom file (some versions are missing since they are declared in parent pom):
Anyone can suggest what may be wrong, please?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tinyradius</groupId>
        <artifactId>tinyradius</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.source-code</groupId>
        <artifactId>minitemplator</artifactId>
        <version>2009.11.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.im4java</groupId>
        <artifactId>im4java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.jre17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sanselan</groupId>
        <artifactId>sanselan</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ser.doxis.blueline.interfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>blueline</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xom</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.renderx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xep</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.renderx</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.renderx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Items which are part of WildFly bsse -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies> 


[INFO] Public resources found in...
[INFO] Translatable source found in...
[INFO] Persistent unit cache dir set to: C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\reponame\projectName\target\gwt-unitCache
[INFO] Opening cache file: C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\reponame\projectName\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-8c530e985114901166261cb2baf5ec75a6e55b9b-FF35F588CF7564DE259004F02565B00E-00000180E19A9E5E
[INFO] Looking for previously cached Compilation Units in C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\reponame\projectName\target\gwt-unitCache
[INFO] Compiling module com.hp.dhl.moduleName.ModuleName
[INFO]    Found 0 cached/archived units.  Used 0 / 3672 units from cache.
[INFO]    Compiling...
[INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 4 seconds)
[INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 4 seconds)
[INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 4 seconds)
[INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 4 seconds)
[INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 4 seconds)
[INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 4 seconds)
[INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
[INFO]       70% complete (ETR: 2 seconds)
[INFO]       80% complete (ETR: 2 seconds)
[INFO]       90% complete (ETR: 1 seconds)
[INFO]       100% complete (ETR: 0 seconds)
[INFO]       Compilation completed in 10.92 seconds
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.visitCompileDependenciesInBytecode(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:226)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker.getCompileDependencySignature(BytecodeSignatureMaker.java:209)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompiledClass.getSignatureHash(CompiledClass.java:166)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:41)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies$Ref.<init>(Dependencies.java:36)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.Dependencies.resolve(Dependencies.java:100)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:349)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:532)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:464)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:210)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:190)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:131)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:192)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:143)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:132)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:110)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:113)
[INFO] Closing cache file: C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\reponame\projectName\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-8c530e985114901166261cb2baf5ec75a6e55b9b-FF35F588CF7564DE259004F02565B00E-00000180E19A9E5E (0 units written)
[INFO] Deleting empty file: C:\Users\myuser\Documents\GitHub\reponame\projectName\target\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-8c530e985114901166261cb2baf5ec75a6e55b9b-FF35F588CF7564DE259004F02565B00E-00000180E19A9E5E
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message/stack trace to the question?

Comment: I posted all what the plugin displayed. 
@ColinAlworth What did you mean? Should I set level to TRACE or paste entire console output?
Anyway, thank you, it looks it started to work, I added an answer.

Comment: There should at least be a stack trace to go with the "unexpected internal compiler error", not just the text itself, anything you can provide there would help to nail this down - though i see you've got some specific things that seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now. What helped was one of three (or all of them):

- replacing `jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec` with `jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec`
- upgrade `asm` to version 8.0.1
- removal of `javax.persistence-api`